# Device does not appear in design mode android studio

Tags: android-studio

In design mode in android studio, the device does not appear. I have tried changing the theme, API version, the device. But the device just does not show up.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the IDE by invalidating cache ?

Comment: I tried that too. But of no use. @Abhishek

Comment: I think your IDE had some error. Check the event log. From the image it's clear that some issue occurred with your IDE. Check that, I think that will solve ur issue. :)